# Adding image alt attribute to a div element within a foreach loop

Tags: jquery, foreach, append

I'm using an overlay plugin and I'd like to populate each 'overlay' div within my foreach loop with the alt attribute from the image nearest to it.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
<div data-overlayer="effect:bottom">
                    <div class="portfolio_slide" data-slides="pager:on; fx:slide">
                        <?php foreach ($page->images as $image) { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image->getThumb('wide'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->description; ?>">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(".overlay").each(function () {
    $(this).append('<p>'function() {
      return $('this').parent('img').attr('alt');
    })'</p>');
});
```

I'm trying to get the alt attribute from each image in the loop and pass it to the empty overlay div. I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my HTML output

```
div data-overlayer="effect:bottom">
                    <div class="portfolio_slide" data-slides="pager:on; fx:slide">
                                                        <img src="/pw_template/site/assets/files/1060/wide_img_0468.jpg" alt="View over Sète">
                                                        <img src="/pw_template/site/assets/files/1060/wide_montpellier.jpg" alt="Beautiful Montpellier at night">
                                                        <img src="/pw_template/site/assets/files/1060/wide_img_0762-1-1.jpeg" alt="Nina relaxing on the lawn">
                                                </div>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `$('this')` should be `$(this)`. Also please post the rendered output instead of the php code

Answer (score 1):

I assume your html structure is like below,

```
     <div data-overlayer="effect:bottom">
         <div class="portfolio_slide" data-slides="pager:on; fx:slide">
                        <img src="someImage.png" alt="Some Alt Text">
         </div>
         <div class="overlay"></div>
     </div>
```

Then your `$.each` should be like below,

```
$(".overlay").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.append('<p>' +  $this.parent().find('img').attr('alt') + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Vega, that adds the description in the overlay except it's always from the same alt tag - the one from the first image in the loop.

Comment: @onjegolders You have 3 `img`s inside the same div. So how do you want the end result to be?

Comment: I need the overlay text to change based on what image in the loop it is. The overlay basically holds the description to each image in the slider

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your method, not sure if you will get it with the included resources? http://jsfiddle.net/25sLM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma and `$('this')` instead of `$(this)`

```
$(".overlay").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).append(function() {
      return '<p>' + $this.closest('div').find('img').attr('alt') + '</p>'
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25sLM/3/)**

Comment: I think the `.append` syntax is incorrect and `</p>` is hanging in the end.

Comment: Thanks Sushanth that adds the comment but it comes up as "undefined"

Comment: @onjegolders .. Here is the updated fiddle..  I have changed the selector a bit as you seem to have multiple images inside the div. Also defined a class container for the parent div.  ..http://jsfiddle.net/25sLM/3/

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth--, that seems to work for the fiddle but not for my slider. See above, my problem was I needed the overlay div within the slider div, that way it stayed within the foreach loop. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution though I feel as though I've misled the jQuery helpers out there.
I needed to put the data-overlayer div inside the data-slides div, that way my image description stayed inside the loop.

Code now as follows:

```
<div class="portfolio_slide" data-slides="pager:on; fx:slide">
                        <?php foreach ($page->images as $image) { ?>
                        <div data-overlayer="effect:bottom">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image->getThumb('wide'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->description; ?>">
                            <div class="overlay"><?php echo $image->description; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

No need for additional jQuery, though I think I will try and learn some more, I don't even know if it's possible to access and set data per item in an array. I guess it must be.

Anyway thanks to @Vega and @Sushanth-- for their help.